# any way to know which link is opened in next tab?

Tags: javascript, php, browser

i would like to know whether there is any option to find or check whether a link is opened in any of the tabs in the browser ,My situation is like ... ,i have created a company website, many of its links are opening to a website(let it be www.wellitsmine.com) on a new tab ,as there are many tabs opening the focus of the company site is not reflecting,i would like to check whether there is any tab have opened up with this link(www.wellitsmine.com),if it is opened then restricting all the links in the company site that have to open www.wellitsmine.com link in new tab.

Comment: It's unclear what your asking. If you want to know what websites a user has open in their browser, the answer is no.

Comment: I believe that's a big security risk. I wouldn't want any JavaScript or extension tracking tabs.

Comment: @relentless yes i would like to know what websites a user has open in their browser?is it possible

Comment: @hjeg It is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **window.postMessage**.

From Your Main Tab,

```
window.postMessage("Your Url As Message", "http://yourcompany.com");
```

Some other tab,

```
window.onmessage = function(e) { if(e.origin == "http://yourcompany.com") /* do your stuff*/};
```

Refer https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.postMessage

Comment: @hjeg You should try to communicate with other instance of your company website using window.postMessage(), if it is not responding then load a url in link target as _blank(new tab|window).

Answer (score 0):

Normally i would recommend using iframes to manage this... But since all the tabs are opening pages from the same domain... what you could do is as such:

```
var wd = window.open('url to your target page');
```

Then the wd object actually is the tab/window that opened.. then you can check if it's closed.. or close it with wd.close().  So insteead of letting links to open up in new tab/window. Use a handler to use window.open and handle those window objects yourself.